# How to simple put button value to jQuery Datatables search input?

Tags: jquery, search, input, datatables

I cannot simple create buttons for put value to jQuery datatable search input, because cannot find the input ID name!
I using "jquery-1.11.3.min.js" & "jquery.dataTables.min.js (v1.10.23)", help me, please!

Comment: Kindly add what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to target the search input directly. You should instead use datatable's `.search()` api. Example

```
var table = $('#table-id').DataTable();
$('button').click(function(){
    table.search( $(this).text() ).draw();
});
```